# Why is BeautifulSoup Returning Duplicate Table Rows and Missing Others Altogether?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape MLB player stats from mlb.com using Selenium and BeautifulSoup and am returning duplicates of many players, and am also missing several others just by giving it the eye test. It's unclear where the duplicates are coming from or why I'm missing others.

I chose to use Selenium instead of Requests because the data is stored in a table, but not visible in the HTML until the browser loads the page. Any ideas where the data integrity errors are coming from?

Thanks in advance!

Highlights from my script below

```
# Navigate to stats page
def getToStats():
    url = ("http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp?c_id=mlb#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2019&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1586832481387&playerType=ALL")
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source

# Get source HTML/CSS
def getCurrentURL():
    url = driver.current_url
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    new_soup = soup.find("tbody")
    return new_soup

def getPlayers(html):
    players = []
    for player in html.find_all('tr'):
        players.append(player)
    return players

def getPlayerStats(player):
    playerRecord = []
    for data in player.find_all('td'):
        stat = data.text.replace('\xa0','') # Removes empty non-ASCII character attached to player last name
        playerRecord.append(stat)
    playerRecord.pop(0) # Removes MLB determined player rank
    playerRecord.pop(2) # Removes empty non-ASCII element
    return playerRecord


##################FUNCTIONS COMPLETE CODE EXECUTION BEGINS######################
playerData = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
getToStats()
html = getCurrentURL()
players = getPlayers(html)
for player in players:
   playerData.append(getPlayerStats(player))

print('Page 1 retrieved')
pageNum = 2
for page in range(25):
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginationWidget-next')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element[0])
    next_html = getCurrentURL()
    playerRecords = getPlayers(next_html)
    for player in playerRecords:
        playerData.append(getPlayerStats(player))
    print('Page ' + str(pageNum) + ' retrieved')
    pageNum = pageNum + 1
print('Found the data')

my_df = pd.DataFrame(playerData)
my_df.to_csv('mlb_stats_2019.csv', index = False, header = False)
print('Enjoy your CSV file')
```

[Duplicate Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3HiK.png)

Comment: Please add your table in text mode as well, in that way is accessible to anyone. I also encourage you to refer to [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script was returning duplicates of some values and skipping others altogether because it was never making it past the second page of the table. It was printing each of the first 50 players (page 1) twice, and then continuously iterating over each of the 50 players on page 2.

I resolved this by using a time.sleep() statement to allow the browser to actually move to the next page prior to trying to scrape the table.

```
pageNum = 1
for player in players:
    playerData.append(getPlayerStats(player))
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginationWidget-next')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element[0])
time.sleep(7)
print('Page 1 retrieved')

# Scrape data for pages 2-26 of the table
pageNum = 2
for page in range(25):
    next_html = getCurrentURL()
    playerRecords = getPlayers(next_html)
    for player in playerRecords:
        playerData.append(getPlayerStats(player))
    print('Page ' + str(pageNum) + ' retrieved')
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginationWidget-next')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element[0])
    pageNum = pageNum + 1
    time.sleep(7)
print('Found the data - placing it in the database')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Google Chrome's developer tool (press F12), and go to network tab, refresh the page. You can find where those data from:
http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2019&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column=%27avg%27&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type=%27R%27&player_pool=ALL&season_type=ANY&sport_code=%27mlb%27&results=1000&recSP=1&recPP=50